# merge two data.frame, keeping all matching rows, in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling to merge two data.frame with na values occuring in one or the other df.

```
sampleA <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "A1MRJ", Rep = 1L, GB05 = 102L, GB05.1 = 102L, 
    GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 169L, 
    GB27.1 = 169L, GB24 = 240L, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = NA_integer_, 
    GB28.1 = NA_integer_, GB15 = 142L, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, 
    GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 126L, GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = 181L, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp", 
"Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1", 
"GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15", 
"GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"
), row.names = 32L, class = "data.frame")


sampleB <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "A1MRJ", Rep = 2L, GB05 = NA, GB05.1 = NA, 
    GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 169L, 
    GB27.1 = 169L, GB24 = 240L, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = 390L, GB28.1 = 390L, 
    GB15 = 142L, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 126L, 
    GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = 181L, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp", 
"Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1", 
"GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15", 
"GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"
), row.names = 33L, class = "data.frame")
```

Output needed, as a data.frame. Only one line every for matching "Nom_xp", so the NA get's replaced by the values in either A or B, if the value exist in one or the other DF.

```
Nom_xp  GB05  GB05  GB18  GB18  GB06  GB06  GB27  GB27  GB24  GB24  GB28    GB28    GB15  GB15  GB02  GB02  GB10  GB10  GB14  GB14
A1MRJ   102 102 177 177 240 240 169 169 240 242 390 390 142 144 197 197 126 134 181 193
```

I would've thought that :

```
output <- merge(A,B,by="Nom_xp",all.x=T,all.y=T)
```

or

```
output <- join(A,B,by="Nom_xp",match="all")
```

would give me what I need, but no luck so far... What am I missing ? Actual data.frame has more than one row.

Comment: Do you have exactly the same lines in sampleA and sampleB, if you ignore the NA's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have just one row? Then, wouldn't this be sufficient? You can get the result in `sampleB` as:

```
sampleB[, is.na(sampleB)] <- sampleA[, is.na(sampleB)]
```

No, apply, join and merge are not necessary here, I think. Not tested, but this would work.

```
sampleB[is.na(sampleB)] <- sampleA[is.na(sampleB)]
```

Comment: No, I have many rows. I haven't thought of using something else than join or merge though... I might be heading in the wrong direction...

Comment: This will work if sampleA and sampleB have the same lines in the same order ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I suggested this because the OP was interested in doing an `apply` before, which made me think that he is comparing row-by-row in replacing values.

Comment: I think comparing row by row will be possible since the two data-frames have the same number of row in the same order. I will try it asap tomorow morning. Thanx a bunch again !

Answer (score 0):

Not entierly sure on how your whole data set looks like but I assume you could have several samples with the same "Nom_xp" and not only 2? And that you probably have all your data in a big dataframe or such?

If so, maybe this code could be a good start (maybe someone can help out and re-write this much much more efficient?). Anyhow:

```
sampleA <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "A1MRJ", Rep = 1L, GB05 = 102L, GB05.1 = 102L, 
                          GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 169L, 
                          GB27.1 = 169L, GB24 = 240L, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = NA_integer_, 
                          GB28.1 = NA_integer_, GB15 = 142L, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, 
                          GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 126L, GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = 181L, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp", "Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1","GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15","GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"), row.names = 32L, class = "data.frame")

sampleB <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "A1MRJ", Rep = 2L, GB05 = NA, GB05.1 = NA, 
                          GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 169L, 
                          GB27.1 = 169L, GB24 = 240L, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = 390L, GB28.1 = 390L, 
                          GB15 = 142L, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 126L, 
                          GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = 181L, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp","Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1", "GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15", "GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"  ), row.names = 33L, class = "data.frame")

sampleC <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "ASDF", Rep = 2L, GB05 = NA, GB05.1 = NA, 
                          GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 12349L, 
                          GB27.1 = 3, GB24 = 234112, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = 234, GB28.1 = 390L, 
                          GB15 = NA, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 126L, 
                          GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = NA, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp", "Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1", "GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15", "GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"), row.names = 34L, class = "data.frame")

sampleD <- structure(list(Nom_xp = "ASDF", Rep = 2L, GB05 = 214, GB05.1 = 34, 
                          GB18 = 177L, GB18.1 = 177L, GB06 = 240L, GB06.1 = 240L, GB27 = 169L, 
                          GB27.1 = 3, GB24 = NA, GB24.1 = 242L, GB28 = 234, GB28.1 = 390L, 
                          GB15 = 56, GB15.1 = 144L, GB02 = 197L, GB02.1 = 197L, GB10 = 15466L, 
                          GB10.1 = 134L, GB14 = 34, GB14.1 = 193L), .Names = c("Nom_xp", "Rep", "GB05", "GB05.1", "GB18", "GB18.1", "GB06", "GB06.1", "GB27", "GB27.1", "GB24", "GB24.1", "GB28", "GB28.1", "GB15", "GB15.1", "GB02", "GB02.1", "GB10", "GB10.1", "GB14", "GB14.1"), row.names = 35L, class = "data.frame")

cdat<-rbind(sampleA,sampleB,sampleC,sampleD) #simulating your data set (?)
dcols<-dim(cdat)[2]

mat<-matrix(nrow=length(unique(cdat$Nom_xp)),ncol=dcols)
colnames(mat)<-colnames(cdat)
for (j in 1:length(unique(cdat$Nom_xp))) 
{
  g<-grep(unique(cdat$Nom_xp)[j],cdat$Nom_xp)   #Get the Nom_xp rows that match
  mat[j,1]<-cdat[g[1],1]                        #Fill in the "Nom_xp"
  mat[j,2]<-paste(g,collapse=" ")               #Fill in the "rep"
  mat[j,3:dcols]<-apply(cdat[g,3:dcols],2,      #Calculate a mean for each column
   function(x){as.numeric(mean(x,na.rm=T))})          
}
```